# Null value while pass values using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am first time using jquery ajax from jscript ajax call.Simply i tried to pass two values from jsp to jsp.Here is what i tried

**JspPage1.jsp**

```
$(function(){
var val1="Some value1";
var val2="Some value2";
$.ajax({url:"JspPage.jsp",
        type:'post',
        data: '{"val1":"' + val1 + '","val2":"' + val2 + '"}',
        success:function(result){
                //here i do nothing

            }});
});
```

**JspPage.jsp**

```
<%
String val1=request.getParameter("val1");
String val2=request.getParameter("val2");

System.out.println("val1 is:"+val1);
System.out.println("val2 is:"+val2);

%>
```

But i am getting `Null` values for both val1 and val2 variables in **JspPage.jsp**.

Where i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem on the paramaters can you please try this:

```
$(function(){
    var val1="Some value1";
    var val2="Some value2";
    $.ajax({
        url: "JspPage.jsp",
        type:"post",
        data: { valone: val1, valtwo: val2 },
        success:function(result){
                alert(result) ;
        }
    });
});
```

and on the server side try it as:

String val1=request.getParameter("valone");
String val2=request.getParameter("valtwo");

Comment: Did you copy and past this piece of code? coz i have the same code working

Comment: Sorry! This code working fine.Actually i did mistake in getting val().Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` stringifies the data you pass. It's not supposed to receive something that's already JSON.

Simply do

```
$.ajax({url:"JspPage.jsp",
    type:'post',
    data: {val1:val1, val2:val2},
    success:function(result){
```

Note that you should never build JSON by concatenating strings as it doesn't do the necessary escapings (and is tedious).

Comment: if i do by your code even page not calling means shows nothing.

Comment: if i do by '{ "val1":"' +val1+'", "val2": "' +val2+'"}' it shows null pointer exception but when i do with  data: {val1:val1, val2:val2} its even not call the page.